vmware before you can run vmware several modules must be compiled and loaded into running kernel Unable to install vmmon and vmnet modules for VMware
I'm having trouble installing the vmmon and vmnet modules required to run VMware Workstation on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS system. I'm using kernel version 6.8.0-40-generic.
Here's the log output I received when trying to install the modules:
Log for VMware Workstation pid=40456 version=17.5.2 build=build-23775571 option=Release
The host is x86_64.
Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
Host is Linux 6.8.0-40-generic Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Ubuntu 22.04 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Host offset from UTC is +03:00.
DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
[msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/sa7/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
[msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/sa7/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/sa7/.vmware/config. Using default values.
Logging to /tmp/vmware-sa7/vmware-40456.log
Obtaining info using the running kernel.
Created new pathsHash.
Setting header path for 6.8.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include".
Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
found symbol version file /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
Read 28974 symbol versions
Reading in info for the vmmon module.
Reading in info for the vmnet module.
Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
"/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
"/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
to be installed: vmmon status: 0
to be installed: vmnet status: 0
Obtaining info using the running kernel.
Setting header path for 6.8.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include".
Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
found symbol version file /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
Read 28974 symbol versions
Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include
Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include
Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
Got gcc version "11".
GCC major version 11 does not match Kernel GCC major version 12.
Attempting to use a compiler at location "/usr/bin/gcc-12".
Got gcc version "12".
The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
Got gcc version "12".
The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "6.8.0-40-generic".
No matching PBM set was found for kernel "6.8.0-40-generic".
The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
Using temp dir "/tmp".
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only'
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Using kernel build system.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/apic.c:19:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/apic.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/comport.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/comport.c:39:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/comport.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.c:29:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.c:89:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:43,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.h:33,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.c:31:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:58:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:110: vmmon.ko] Error 2
Using kernel build system.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac_compat.h:30,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac.c:57:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/hub.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/hub.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac_compat.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/driver.c:48:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/userif.c:46:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/driver.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/procfs.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/procfs.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-k9mAMw/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:110: vmnet.ko] Error 2
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
Using temp dir "/tmp".
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only'
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only'
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Using kernel build system.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/apic.c:19:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/comport.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/comport.c:39:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/apic.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/comport.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.c:29:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.c:89:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_assert.h:43,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.h:33,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.c:31:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:58:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vmware.h:37,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmmon-only] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:110: vmmon.ko] Error 2
Using kernel build system.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac_compat.h:30,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac.c:57:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac_compat.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/driver.c:48:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/driver.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/userif.c:46:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/userif.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/hub.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/hub.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/procfs.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/procfs.o] Error 1
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnet.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:24,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/vm_basic_types.h:130:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
  130 | #include <stdint.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only/bridge.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-O92BdV/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:110: vmnet.ko] Error 2
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

I've noticed the following issues in the log:
The script seems to have trouble finding the kernel header path: /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
The GCC version (11) doesn't match the kernel GCC version (12). However, it attempts to use gcc-12 later on.
The script mentions "No matching PBM set was found for kernel 6.8.0-40-generic". I'm unsure what this means.
I've tried searching online for solutions, but haven't found anything specific to my situation.
I tried sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all but the output is for the same issue
Any help on how to successfully install the vmmon and vmnet modules would be greatly appreciated.

I see you're using vmWare Workstation 17.5.2
Michal Kubeček maintains code that makes player and workstation work with more recent kernels. You're using kernel 6.8.0-40-generic, which is not supported (right now). You'll need to use 6.8.0-38.
Main Steps:

Reboot and downgrade kernel
Get vmWare patch
Install vmware patch

Reboot and downgrade kernel

Press and hold the shift key during boot
Grub menu will display - select Advanced options for Ubuntu
Choose 6.8.0-38-generic

Get vmWare patch
You'll need to get Michal Kubeček's patch. Here's the install instructions::
https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/blob/master/INSTALL
As of 2024.08.18, the most recent version is a patch for 17.5.1 (and it works with workstation 17.5.2).
Paste each of the following lines into console to download and install.
wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-17.5.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf workstation-17.5.1.tar.gz
cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1

Install vmware patch
Per the instructions above, make sure you're in the extracted vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1 folder, and paste each line into console:
sudo make
sudo make install

You should now be able to run vmWare.

thanks, the app stared but, when i opened any vm. this 3 messages appeared and terminated.
"Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded."
"Failed to initialize monitor device."
"Unable to change virtual machine power state: Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken."

There's a fork available from nan0desu with the various patches applied so vmWare 17.5.2 works with more recent kernels (6.8.0-45-generic and 6.9). Per this post: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/issues/264 and the instructions: https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/issues/264#issuecomment-2267573220

Worked, Thanks.
